# Persistence usb drive debian not working correctly on bios legacy

Tags: linux, boot, usb, debian, bios

I tried installing debian lxqt with persistence partition on usb by selecting persistence partition on rufus (bios and uefi mode) and also from this thread [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382817/uefi-bios-bootable-live-debian-stretch-buster-bullseye-amd64-with-persistence), but i end up getting the same result - on uefi based computers it works all good and the data from persistence drive is correctly loading, but on bios legacy based the debian boots and loads correctly but persistence data isnt loading dirrectly to the main system catalogs, i only can reach it on persistence partition by mounting it and finding the data. How may i fix this?

Comment: [CSM \[Legacy\] Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) should never be used, as its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 _(since 2017, all distros have supported EFI boot AFAIK)_. The only time it should ever be enabled is if needing to access a legacy OPROM, and once done in the OPROM, it should be re-disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Rufus dev here.

I can replicate your issue. The problem is that whereas Rufus needs to patch the Isolinux/Syslinux (BIOS) and GRUB (UEFI) config files for persistence, it appears that Debian split their Isolinux/Syslinux config files further since last time we tested, so the current version of Rufus only properly patches the GRUB (UEFI) config files.

I'll have a fix for this in the next version of Rufus, but in the meantime, you should manually edit `\isolinux\live.cfg` and add the `persistence` keyword to the `append` line so that it reads something like:

```
append boot=live persistence components quiet splash
```

Then you should find that persistence also works with BIOS mode.

Oh, and for the record, you can always report issues that have to do with Rufus in the [public Rufus issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!